# Function returning NaN and not counting properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a counter that counts the time down but it is returning NaN and not counting down.

I have more than one counters. One that counts-down, another that counts-up until `stoptime` and one more that counts after `stoptime`, which is `Overtime`. But this one is returning NaN and others are not working or counting.

```
  function fixIntegers(integer) {
      if (integer < 0) integer = 0;
      if (integer < 10) return '0' + integer;
      return '' + integer;
  }

  function TimeCount(difference) {
      var toReturn = {
          weeks: 0,
          days: 0,
          hours: 0,
          minutes: 0,
          seconds: 0
      };
      toReturn.seconds = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
      difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

      toReturn.minutes = fixIntegers(difference % 60);
      difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);

      toReturn.hours = fixIntegers(difference % 24);
      difference = Math.floor(difference / 24);

      toReturn.days = fixIntegers(difference % 7);
      difference = Math.floor(difference / 7);

      toReturn.weeks = fixIntegers(difference);
      return toReturn;
  }



  var InThisDiv = $(this).parents().eq(0); // Parent

  var NowTime = new Date(); //Time Now
  var StartTime = new Date(InThisDiv.find('.StartTime').val());
  var StopTime = new Date(InThisDiv.find('.StopTime').val());

  if (StartTime < NowTime && NowTime < StopTime) {
      var diff = TimeCount(Math.floor((NowTime - StartTime) / 1000));
      output = (parseInt(diff, 10) + 2);
      console.log(output.weeks);
  } else if (StopTime < NowTime) {
      var output = TimeCount(Math.floor((StopTime - StartTime) / 1000));
  } else if (NowTime > StopTime) {
      var output = TimeCount(Math.floor((NowTime - StopTime) / 1000));
  } else {
      var output = TimeCount(Math.floor((StopTime - NowTime) / 1000));
  }

 console.log(output.weeks);
```

Thanks in advance. Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALjT9/
EDIT: 
Added HTML  New FIddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ALjT9/4/

Comment: Your fiddle contains no html.

Comment: no html -> `.val()` doesn't return the right thing -> invalid argument to `new Date()` -> invalid date -> NaN

Comment: I have added the HTML. New Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/ALjT9/4/

Answer (score 0):

You're JS is looking for and element that is non-existent (at least in your fiddle)

```
  var StartTime = new Date(InThisDiv.find('.StartTime').val());
  var StopTime = new Date(InThisDiv.find('.StopTime').val());
```

You need to make sure these elements are in the DOM and make sure they have a value.